# We writing pixel values in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am working with the [Ocean Color SMI: Standard Mapped Image MODIS Aqua Data dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_OCEANDATA_MODIS-Aqua_L3SMI#bands).

Using the Sea Surface Temperature band, I am trying to assign the value "0" to any pixel in my region that has a value less than 30. Conversely, I need to assign a "1" to a pixel that has a value greater than or equal to 30. Essentially, some sort of binary process on the pixel data so that then when I visualize the map, there will be only two colors, the "0" and the "1."

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the comparison operation: `image.gte(30)`. This will return an image whose pixel values are mapped to 0 and 1 exactly as you are looking for.

(You can also compare to another image; in fact, writing a number is equivalent to constructing and comparing against a constant-valued image.)

Comment: Thank you! So simply this should work? (Filtered for the month of April 2012 and ROI is my region) 

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI').select('sst')
                  .filterDate('2012-04-01', '2012-04-30')
                  .filterBounds(ROI);
var modis = dataset.median();
var m= modis.gte(30);
Map.addLayer(m.clip(ROI),{},'Binary');